# Como limpar o conteúdo de uma variável dentro de uma função JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, jquery-ui

Estou começando a estudar Javascript e JqueryUi estou desenvolvendo a seguinte página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando eu clico numa nova data o antigo não é resetado conforme Print abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo criar uma função de Reset, usar o .remove mas nada funciona.
Gostaria de uma ajuda!
Segue os meu código:

```js
$(function() {
InciaData();
MostraData();

});

$.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
 closeText: 'Fechar',
 prevText: '&lt;Anterior',
 nextText: 'Próximo&gt;',
 currentText: 'Hoje',
 monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho',
 'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
 monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun',
 'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
 dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Terça-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sabado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
 dayNamesMin: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
 weekHeader: 'Sm',
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 firstDay: 0,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: ''
}

function InciaData(){
 //passa formato local
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
 //aplica o datepicker 
 $( "#date" ).datepicker();

 $( "#date" ).change( function () {
 //alert("ok");

 var valor =$("#date").val();
 var frase = $(".frase").text();


 var n3 = frase+valor; 
 $(".frase").text(n3).attr('style', 'color:orange;');

});
$(".frase")= $(".frase").val(" ");
}



function MostraData(){
 var barra =$( "#mostraData" );
 barra.draggable();
}
```

```css
body{
 width: 940px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.headerTeste{
 width: 25.0rem;
 height: 15.0rem;
 background-image: url(http://www. 88.com.br/assets/img/ 88.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
main p{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-widget-header{
 background-color: #80e5ff;
 color:white;
}
#mostraData{
 margin-top: 3rem;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 0.5em;
 background-color: #66ffcc; 
}
.frase{
 color:black;
}

#mostraData:hover { 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -mos-transform:scale(1.5);
 transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste agora</title>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloM2g.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/scriptJqueryUi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="headerTeste">
  
 </header>
<main>
  <p>Escolha uma Data:</p>
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date">

  <div id="mostraData">
      <p class="frase">Podem me arrastar: </p>

  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde está o trecho que está limpando? A função reset ou só o trecho mesmo..

Comment: Lucas Costa, na função InciaData().

Comment: Tente usar isto : "var valor = $("#date").val();
$(".frase").text("Podem me arrastar: "+valor).attr('style', 'color:orange;');"

No trecho que está assim atualmente : "var valor =$("#date").val();
 var frase = $(".frase").text();


 var n3 = frase+valor; 
 $(".frase").text(n3).attr('style', 'color:orange;');";

Comment: Lucas Costa funcionou sim, muito obrigada pela sua ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão, seria colocar um SPAN, e setar o valor, data, dentro dele, fica mais simples o código, desde que a frase não mude. Fica como abaixo:

```
<div id="mostraData">
    <p class="frase">Podem me arrastar: </p>
    <span id="valData"></span>
</div>
```

No código JS, fica:

```
function InciaData(){
    //passa formato local
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    //aplica o datepicker 
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();

    $( "#date" ).change( function () {
        $("#valData").text($("#date").val());           
    });
}
```

Comment: Sim simplifica muito mesmo Celso.                                                             
Ambas respostas estão corretas porém só a do Celso está habilitada para escolher como resposta correta.                                                                 Obrigada Meninos!